Azure Open AI With Llama_index
I am encountering an error when using llama_index in conjunction with the example provided on the llama_index website. The example can be found at the following link:
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/customization/llms/AzureOpenAI/
    query = "explain Scaled Dot-Product Attention in short and bullets"
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    answer = query_engine.query(query)
    answer.response

your text
AttributeError: type object 'AzureOpenAI' has no attribute 'metadata'
Help me to solve this problem.
